# Error with adding an attribute in html. How can i do fix it?

Tags: javascript, html, href

im trying to use skype for making a chat with Html and javascript.
The problem here is that I can't add the attribute href to my id.

here my code:

```js
function el(elementId, username, action) {
    document.getElementById(elementId).setAttribute("href", "skype:" + username + "?" + action);
}

function buildLinkRefs() {
    var username = document.getElementById("username").value;

    el("call-btn", username, "call");
    el("add-to-contacts-btn", username, "add");
    el("view-profile-btn", username, "userinfo");
    el("voice-email-btn", username, "voicemail");
    el("chat-btn", username, "chat");
    el("sendfile-btn", username, "sendfile");
}

document.getElementById("username").addEventListener("change", function () {
    buildLinkRefs();
}, false);

buildLinkRefs();
```

```html
    <input type="text" id="username" value="echo123"/><br>
    <br>
    <a id="call-btn">Call</a> <br>
    <a id="add-to-contacts-btn">Add to contacts</a> <br>
    <a id="view-profile-btn">View User Profile</a> <br>
    <a id="voice-email-btn">Voice Email</a> <br>
    <a id="chat-btn">Start Chat</a> <br>
    <a id="sendfile-btn">Send File</a> <br>
```

Comment: What error are you getting?

Comment: you don't need to ```setAttribute``` for href on ```<a>``` tag, just call ```document.getElementById(elementId).href = ...```

Comment: Your example works on load just not when typing in the username, in your event listener change `change` to `input` or `keyup`.

Comment: Sorry for not saying the problem well.
So, my problem is that i cant href the <a> with my script, and i cant understand why.

Comment: Not fixed at all @asdru

Answer (score 1):

You are using the wrong event listener. A text input should use "keyup", not "change"

```
document.getElementById('username').addEventListener('keyup', buildLinkRefs );
```

So, using your code, it should look like this:

```js
function el(elementId, username, action) {
    document.getElementById(elementId).setAttribute("href", "skype:" + username + "?" + action);
}

function buildLinkRefs() {
    var username = document.getElementById("username").value;

    el("call-btn", username, "call");
    el("add-to-contacts-btn", username, "add");
    el("view-profile-btn", username, "userinfo");
    el("voice-email-btn", username, "voicemail");
    el("chat-btn", username, "chat");
    el("sendfile-btn", username, "sendfile");
}

document.getElementById("username").addEventListener("keyup", buildLinkRefs );

buildLinkRefs();
```

```html
<input type="text" id="username" value="echo123"/><br>
    <br>
    <a id="call-btn">Call</a> <br>
    <a id="add-to-contacts-btn">Add to contacts</a> <br>
    <a id="view-profile-btn">View User Profile</a> <br>
    <a id="voice-email-btn">Voice Email</a> <br>
    <a id="chat-btn">Start Chat</a> <br>
    <a id="sendfile-btn">Send File</a> <br>
```

Comment: thanks for the answer, but changing the keyup didn't add the href to my <a> :(

Comment: I just notice that if i run the code on this responde, i get what i need. Maybe its something on my computer.

Answer (score 0):

The problem is that your function is **fired** before  the entire page is loaded thus it doesn' t see the element `username` because the element is not available .So there are many ways to solve it . Just put your code after or below your html element as illustred below :

```
<html>
 <head>
    <title>the title</title>
 </head>
     <body>
       <input type="text" id="username" value="echo123"/><br>
   <br>
    <a id="call-btn">Call</a> <br>
    <a id="add-to-contacts-btn">Add to contacts</a> <br>
    <a id="view-profile-btn">View User Profile</a> <br>
    <a id="voice-email-btn">Voice Email</a> <br>
    <a id="chat-btn">Start Chat</a> <br>
    <a id="sendfile-btn">Send File</a> <br>

    <!-- ### PLACE HERE YOUR CODE AFTER YOUR HTML CONTENT     -->
    <script type="text/javascript" language="javascript">
         function el(elementId, username, action) {
             document.getElementById(elementId).setAttribute("href", "skype:" + 
              username + "?" + action);
         }

    function buildLinkRefs() {
        var username = document.getElementById("username").value;

        el("call-btn", username, "call");
        el("add-to-contacts-btn", username, "add");
        el("view-profile-btn", username, "userinfo");
        el("voice-email-btn", username, "voicemail");
        el("chat-btn", username, "chat");
        el("sendfile-btn", username, "sendfile");
      }

     document.getElementById("username").addEventListener("change", function () {
         buildLinkRefs();
     }, false);

    buildLinkRefs(); 
</script>
```